# Complicated battery boot jump

Tags: voltage, batteries, dual

2x 300watt solar with 2x 12volt battery’s …
I want to have a 3 phase switch.
Left switch is battery 1
Middle switch is both battery’s off.
Right switch is battery 2.

What switch that can carry 1000 watt power without burning out the switch.

How can I be certain the switch is capable of the job and not getting some 240volt AC switch.

I use battery 1 for a day or until it gets low and switch over.
I don’t want them both hooked up as I may drain accidentally

The next part is to have a 500watt inverter to run a small kettle.
Can I hook up both left and right power cables to the inverter knowing I’m only on or using one battery.

Thanks

Comment: Switches are rated for current and DC voltage not load power. consider FET's and define the interface better.

Comment: Accidentally drain batteries below 11.5V will shorten battery life. This needs a cutoff circuit. Having a DMM to monitor battery voltage and regulate loads with 2 batteries together might be better to cutoff loads automatically at some threshold like 12V

Comment: That's a 3 position switch. 3 phase won't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Look on Amazon or elsewhere for "Battery Selector Switch" - these switches are widely used in boats and RVs to switch between batteries.

They typically allow you to select between Battery 1, Battery 2, Both batteries, or Off.

They will have no problem carrying the current you require.

Comment: Exactly this. These switches are usually specified for 100A DC current or more. I would add: look for a well-specified switch of a known brand or buy in a more specialized store.

Comment: Fantastic.. I will pop down the marina this weekend and have a probe round to see if anyone round there has this kind of setup. Might get some good advice from them if they use these switches.
Excellent advice *****